Getting Error in the below specified line
driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL ("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),cap);
I am getting error in this line as:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/internal/JsonToWebElementConverter
Why is it not working?

Because  /wd/hub is removed in Appium 2.0, so you should use http://127.0.0.1:4723 for appium server url.
